# PhpStorm debug issue

Tags: php, apache, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

I have the issue with the debugging application on local apache server with PhpStorm. After Apache is started the breakpoint is reached for the very first time, which is a good behavior and I can debug the part of code.
However then I refresh the page in web browser and the breakpoint is not reached anymore, until I restart apache. Once apache is restarted I can reach the breakpoint - but just for the very first time.

Has anyone of you had such issue?

Comment: Please state your PhpStorm, PHP and Xdebug versions. Solution/workaround depends on what you have got there/what you can do.

Comment: PhpStorm 2020.3
PHP 7.2.20 (cli) (built: Jul  2 2019 13:01:33) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.7.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2019, by Derick Rethans

Comment: As a hint: try to update your environment from time to time - XDebug 2.7.2 is more than a year old, PHP 7.2.20 is also pretty outdated, and there are always bugs fixed in later versions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - PhpStorm 2020.3
> - PHP 7.2.20
> - Xdebug v2.7.2

This is a result of fixing [WI-51991](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-51991) in PhpStorm 2020.3 -- done on request from Xdebug author (Xdebug ticket [#1756](https://bugs.xdebug.org/1756)).

Sadly Xdebug **2.9.3 and older** [has a bug (ticket #1766)](https://bugs.xdebug.org/1766) that turns off remote debugging for the remainder of the duration of this specific PHP process (that's why only first request works) -- fixed in Xdebug 2.9.4.

### Solution:

**Upgrade Xdebug to 2.9.6 or newer** (latest versions are Xdebug 2.9.8 for 2.x branch and 3.0.1 for v3) -- it's confirmed working there by multiple people.

*Looks like you are on Windows. In such case get the latest version here: https://xdebug.org/download (just get the right build, I believe you need "PHP 7.2 VC15 TS (64 bit)":  [v3.0.1](https://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-3.0.1-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll) or [2.9.8](https://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-2.9.8-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll))*

Alt approach: keep using previous 2020.2.4 or wait for 2020.3.1 where some workaround will be implemented for Xdebug v2.x ([WI-57577](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-57577)) -- [2020.3.1 Preview build](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2020/12/phpstorm-2020-3-1-preview/) is already available; final version should be released at some point later this month.

**NOTES:**

- [Comment by Derick Rethans](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-56500#focus=Comments-27-4594687.0-0) (Xdebug author)
- Xdebug 2.9 is [no longer supported](https://xdebug.org/docs/compat)
- If you decide to use Xdebug v3 (which you should; it's available for your PHP 7.2) -- it uses DIFFERENT config parameters, so please go through [Upgrading from Xdebug 2 to 3 Guide](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide) and update (mostly rename) your Xdebug config.